# Disable extensions on chrome pop up window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, firefox, window

I am working on a new project that requires high security.

I want to protect the user input from being scraped by a malicious browser extension, so is there a way i can use `window.open()` and specify that the window has chrome extensions disabled or prevent the access of the extensions on my site?

I looked in the MDN documentation on the options I can give to `window.open()` but did't find anything useful.